# How can I match the url in html

Tags: python, django

```
<form action='/[0-9]+' method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="delete question" name="delete">
</form>
```

what above is the html template I am using for the appengine project. Besides that, i created a web request handler class to handle this request. **('/[0-9]+',QuestionViewer)**, it is supposed to catch any url in digits. However, turns on that after I click on the delete button above, my page is directed to some url like main/[0-9], I dont know if I can use regex in the django template, or is there a away that my QuestionViewers class can catch  the url in digits? since my url associated with the html page is dynamic, like the parts after / ,like /13,are changing accordingly and I cant do   that only works for page 13 but not for /14 or something like these. Hope I make it clear. any helps? Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't really make sense. You want to submit your form to a regex rule? What would it match against?

No, the form needs to submit to a specific url. Right now, it's trying to submit to `/[0-9]+`

If I understand what you are saying, and you want to submit from a url such as `/13/` to your `QuestionViewer` at `/[0-9]+`, simply submit without the `action` attribute or set it to `""` to post to the current url.

Note that if you want to use the digit captured in your regex, you need to surround your regex in parenthesis such as `'/([0-9]+)/$', QuestionViewer` or use a named regexp `/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$` to pass in an argument of `id` equal to the matched regex to `QuestionViewer`.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request

Answer (score 0):

The value of the action attribute must be a valid URL.

I think what you want is to generate an actual number for the action url; a number that is the number of the question that you want to delete. For example:

```
<form action="/1234" method="POST">
```

You will need to change your code to make sure you do this.